# The website template downloaded as HTML does not work properly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, themes

I downloaded the alpariforex.org/fa/ site template as HTML and everything is fine, but the slider, menus, and tab bar don't work. Apparently it's with Vue that doesn't work properly in HTML. Can anyone guide me?

http://alpariforex.org/fa/

How can I download the template of this site completely?

Comment: the slider and menu tabs don't work its because it requires the functionality of JavaScript i.e.  vue js